# Как заблокировать IEnumerable от изменений?

Tags: c#, linq

Здравствуйте, проблема в следующем: в приложении на С#, использую `LinqToSQL` для работы с локальной БД. Содержимое таблицы сохраняю в `Ienumerable<>`.

При отладке поставил breakpoint'ы на всех местах, где изменяю запрос, результаты которого сохраняю в `Ienumerable<My_Type> lvl2_query`, при запуске программы ни в один из них не попадаю, а содержимое `lvl2_query` меняется.

Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Comment: Вопрос решен, дело в моем незнании:( У меня lvl2_query присваивался запросу, где участвовала глобальная переменная num, которая постоянно менялась в программе, и при изменении которой, как я понял, пересчитывался весь запрос. Заменил в запросе num на локальную переменную, и проблема исчезла+программа стала быстрей работать.

Answer (score 2):

Вы поставили точки останова на всех местах, где **изменяете** запрос. Этого недостаточно. Необходимо поставить точки останова на всех местах, где **сохраняются** результаты запроса в  коллекцию.

По существу IEnumerable **является** неизменяемой, поскольку нельзя напрямую менять значение элементов коллекции, но можно через ссылки менять значения объектов на которые ссылаются элементы коллекции.

Вы можете преобразовать IEnumerable в ReadOnlyCollection, но это  мало что изменит.

**Добавление.**

Чтобы выяснить, в чем дело, можно создать простой класс-обертку над коллекцией, который будет обеспечивать печать в лог при доступе, содержащее данные, которые вносятся в класс, например, строку кода, где происходит запись (для этого удобно использовать класс `StackFrame`). Что-то вроде такого

```
class Wrapper {
    private IEnumerable collection;
    public IEnumerable Collection {
        get {
            return collection;
        }
        set {
            StackFrame frame = new StackFrame( 1, true );
            string method = frame.GetMethod().ToString();
            string file = frame.GetFileName();
            int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

            Debug.WriteLine("Запись в коллекцию");
            // Вывод значений переменных
            // ...

            collection = value;
        }
    }
}
```

И вместо

```
IEnumerable x = ...
```

будет

```
Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

w.Collection = ...
```

Comment: Я поставил БП всюду, где есть lvl2_query=anything, где еще?

Comment: Уточните проблему: у вас меняется сама коллекция: количество и состав элементов, или конкретные объекты из этой коллекции?

Comment: У меня в БД есть таблица My_Types, которая содержит информацию о типах одежды (название типа, ID,ID родительского типа..), и в коде описывается классом Types. После очередного запроса 
lv2_query=from tmp in My_Types where... в lvl2_query содержится 3 елемента типа Types. После чего я продолжаю выполнение программы ( с БП на всех присваиваниях lvl2_query + БП на начале процедуры обработки нажатия кнопки) и жму на кнопку, попадаю на мой БП, смотрю содержимое lvl2_query, и там уже содержится 1 элемент типа Types, при чем не из числа предыдущих 3.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Итак:) Со StackFrame не вполне разобрался, но сделал проще: поставил БП сразу после входа в set свойства lvl2_query класа wrapper, все lvl2_query=.. заменил на wrapper.lvl2_query=..., та же беда: в БП не заходит, содержимое wrapper.lvl2_query меняется...

Comment: Началось это после написания одного запроса.Поменял чуть-чуть запрос, теперь работает,но через раз.Появился другой вопрос:Хочу получить ID родительского типа по ID подтипа,и использовать в запросе.Пишу что-то вроде этого:
lvl2_query=from tp in My_Types where tp.Parent_ID==(from ttp in My_Types where ttp.ID=selected_ID select ttp.Parent_ID).Но подзапрос возвращает коллекцию,а не int?,хотя ID - первичный ключ,и полюбому вернется либо одна запись,либо ничего,то-есть должно работать.Собственно вопрос: как сделать так,чтобы получить только Parent_ID?(я использовал Max(),но врядли так надо делать)

Answer (score 1):

Например, так: [readonly list or unmodifiable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984042).